# FindGLM.cmake not in glm 0.9.7, is it a deprecated way to find libraries in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, glm-math

So looking through the newest release of GLM 0.9.7, I dont see a FindGLM.cmake file anywhere, used to easily include GLM in CMAKE. I could always use an old version of it found online but the following commit had me stumped:

https://github.com/g-truc/glm/commit/62a7daddcf082f754000fc5e42d7bcdf93c895f7

Commit message is "Removed obsolete FindGLM". So, did the developer just dump it or are there in fact a new way to find libraries in CMAKE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, CMake Find modules (`FindXyz.cmake` files) are deprecated in favour of Package Config files (usually named `XyzConfig.cmake`). The original philosophy is that Find modules are shipped and maintained by CMake, while Package Config files are shipped and maintained by the package they are intended to find.

CMake's [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command actually has two modes: Module mode (legacy, using Find modules) and Config mode (preferred, using Package Config files).

For the client consuming the package, little should change (unless more customisation is desired, which is offered by the Config mode of `find_package`).

Notice that the very commit to which you linked not only drops `FindGLM.cmake`, but also adds a `glmConfig.cmake` file.