# GLM linking in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, glm-math

I cannot link glm library with my executable. I tried link via
`${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, `${GLM_LIBRARIES}` and `${GLM_LIBRARY_DIRS}` cmake variables but it does not work.

How can I link libraries and inludes of glm with my executable?

I am using `find_package()` method :

```
find_package(glm REQUIRED PATHS "${GLM_BINARY_DIR}" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

And does not have any problem with `find_package()`  but these status messages below displays nothing :

```
message(STATUS "GLM includes ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "GLM libraries ${GLM_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Config* script for GLM defines IMPORTED target `glm::glm`.
So the correct way for use GLM in CMake code is to link with that target.
This is explicitly written in the [documentation](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/manual.md#-15-finding-glm-with-cmake):

```
set(glm_DIR <installation prefix>/lib/cmake/glm) # if necessary
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(<your executable> glm::glm)
```

---

Variables like `GLM_LIBRARIES` or `GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS` are usually defined by *Find* scripts (shipped with CMake or with the consumer project).

*Config* scripts, shipped with the installed package, normally defines IMPORTED targets.

GLM doesn't have a Find script (see [FindGLM.cmake not in glm 0.9.7, is it a deprecated way to find libraries in CMAKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634850/findglm-cmake-not-in-glm-0-9-7-is-it-a-deprecated-way-to-find-libraries-in-cmak)), and `PATHS` option in `find_package` invocation explicitly requests Config script.

Comment: I used this method, however I'm receiving the following error:
`
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (target_link_libraries):
  The plain signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with
  the target "simulator".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target
  must be either all-keyword or all-plain.

  The uses of the plain signature are here:

   * CMakeLists.txt:11 (target_link_libraries)
`

Comment: @AbrahamZsomborNagy: You have **searched** for that error message, haven't you? Have you found e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522268/3440745)? It describes how to solve the error.

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev, no I haven't found this, it solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

My approach was wrong.

From OpenGL GLM offical page:

> OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) is a header only C++ mathematics library for graphics software based on the OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) specifications.

So, I just need to specify the `/include` path of builded GLM library in which the linker should search for libraries when linking a given target.

That can be handled by cmake `target_include_directories()` function. This fixed my problem :

```
target_include_directories(myExecutable "${GLM_BINARY_DIR}/include")
```

`${GLM_BINARY_DIR}` is defined by me and points to the where GLM binaries are stored.